# Is it safe to run multiple `pip install` commands at the same time?

Tags: python, installation, pip

Suppose I am running pip install for a large library, which is taking a long time to install. Is it safe to run additional pip installs at the same time? (in a different shell, but the same environment)

Comment: I'm uncertain, but I bet a race condition is possible with dependency resolution

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it is safe to run additional pip installs in a different shell or command prompt while another pip installation process is running in the background. This is because each shell or command prompt instance has its own interpreter session and environment, so they won't interfere with each other.

However, keep in mind that running multiple pip installations simultaneously can put additional load on your system's resources (CPU, memory, disk I/O) and may slow down all the installations. Additionally, if there are any shared dependencies between the packages being installed, this could lead to version conflicts or errors.

So, while it is theoretically safe to do so, it is generally not recommended to run multiple pip installs at the same time, especially if you're installing large libraries. It's better to wait for one installation to finish before starting another one to avoid potential issues or performance problems. If you need to install multiple libraries, you could create a requirements.txt file with all the dependencies and install them together using `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: In which case would there be conflicts with shared dependencies that would not occur with two sequential pip installs?